# Show Tax Amount but don't include in SubTotal & Grand Total

Tags: magento-1.9, tax, system-configuration

i need help regarding **Magento 1.9.2**, i want to show the Tax amount but don't want to include in **SubTotal** and in **GrandTotal** amount.

i have already play around with Tax Settings 
**admin-->System-->Configuration-->Sales-->Tax-->Shopping Cart Display Settings**

But still no Result. i have also visit similar question's post on this Forum or any other forums but all in vain.

Please have look on the image below

[image]

Anyone Please help to purpose any solution.

Thanks.

Comment: where you want to show tax amount @Crumby?

Comment: @NagarajJuro i have included the Image for better understanding.